# RemoteFileTemplate throws 'remoteDirectoryExpression' is required when using SftpOutboundGateway

Tags: spring-integration

I'm using the DSL API way for configuring an SftpOutboundGateway for issuing custom commands. In the example below I'm uploading a file and move it remotely afterwards:

```
public IntegrationFlow sftpOutboundFlow() {
    return from(getFileToSftpChannel()).handle(Sftp.outboundGateway(getSftpSessionFactory(), PUT, "dir")).handle(Sftp.outboundGateway(getSftpSessionFactory(), MV, "dir")).channel(new NullChannel()).get();
```

But, when I run this, I get:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'remoteDirectoryExpression' is required
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115)
at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.send(RemoteFileTemplate.java:276)
at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.send(RemoteFileTemplate.java:272)
at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.doPut(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:597)
```

The reason is that RemoteFileTemplate is supposed to be initialized by Spring (InitializingBean, BeanFactoryAware) but it is not:

**AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway**

```
/**
 * Construct an instance with the supplied session factory, a command ('ls', 'get'
 * etc), and an expression to determine the filename.
 * @param sessionFactory the session factory.
 * @param command the command.
 * @param expression the filename expression.
 */
public AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway(SessionFactory<F> sessionFactory, Command command, String expression) {
    this(new RemoteFileTemplate<F>(sessionFactory), command, expression);
}
```

Is this a bug or am I using this incorrectly? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not fully a bug...

The `remoteDirectoryExpression` is an option of `RemoteFileTemplate` which can be injected to the `Sftp.outboundGateway()` since Spring Integration Java DSL 1.1.

Comment: Ok, so I read that the way I'm using it is not working because of a bug (where I can log this ticket?) and the alternative/workaround is injecting the RemoteFileTemplate myself. Correct?

Comment: OK. If you'd like you can raise it here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/issues. And even contribute the fix !